# Airflow SQL Server stored procedure does not complete

Tags: stored-procedures, airflow

We are moving some stored procedure from being executed in SQL Server jobs to Airflow.

I use the following template to execute them:

```
usp = MsSqlOperator(
    mssql_conn_id='mysqlconnection',
    task_id='Run usp',
    sql= r"""EXEC dbo.usp""",
    autocommit=True
)
```

The stored procedure starts but never completes.

The stored procedure will store data in temp tables, do some transformations, and do a merge and update.

It takes less than 30 seconds to execute, going through Airflow it takes forever to execute. Never actually seems to end.

What I tried:

- make sure the stored procedure starts --> ok
- identify the part where the stored procedure get stuck --> merge-update statement
- run the stored procedure with Airflow user on ssms --> it works
- run other stored procedures with the same template --> they all work
- check table locks --> none

One hint I have is the size of the destination table, when using an empty table it works but when I load this dummy table with the actual data it fails.

The size of the table is 73M rows (around 20GB).

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know how to solve it?